# Approximation formula for Higher-order derivative

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I have this assigment

> Derive by using Taylor approximation of $f$ a formula for approximation of $f′(x_0),f′′(x_0),f′′′(x_0),f′′′′(x_0)$ with an error term of order $h^4$.

I have already done $f′(x_0)$ and $f′′(x_0)$ but I'm stuck trying to get $f'''(x)$. I've done the Taylor expansion for $f(x+h),f(x-h),f(x+2h),f(x-2h),f(x+3h),f(x-3h)$ and don't know what else to do.

Can someone give me some advice o help me to get $f'''(x)$?

PD Excuse my bad English.

**EDIT:**

What the assigment want me to get is something like

$f'''(x)= \frac{-f(x+3h)+8f(x+2h)-13f(x+h)+13f(x-h)-8f(x-2h)+f(x-3h)}{8h^3}+O(h^4)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: read Section 1.2 of [this text](https://www.siam.org/books/ot98/sample/OT98Chapter1.pdf).

Comment: Hi, thnks but I dont get exactly how to get from [there](https://www.siam.org/books/ot98/sample/OT98Chapter1.pdf) to the formula I just added. Sorry for mentioned it just now.

Comment: I was able to solve it, by other methods. But the it was very useful. Thnks.